# Equating sidebar height to main column height

Tags: jquery, height, sidebar

I need my sidebar to be as tall as my main content column, so I execute this code :

```
var main_column_height = jQuery("#main_column").height();  
jQuery("#sidebar").css('height', main_column_height);
```

.. in my jQuery(function(){}). It works most of the time, but sometimes it doesn't. Same if I put the code in jQuery(window).bind("load", function(){}).

How to make it works all the time ?

Comment: Can you provide an example, either here or in jsFiddle?

Comment: especially an example when it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

try [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin.

```
$(function() {
    var main_column_height = jQuery("#main_column").outerHeight();  
    jQuery("#sidebar").css('height', main_column_height);
})
```